# Patch Method with Extend User Model in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a Patch method with Extend User Model in Django Rest Framework.

**My Extend User Model:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    bio = models.CharField
```

**My serializers:**

```
class UserEditSerializer(ModelSerializer):
bio = serializers.CharField(source='profile.bio')
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'bio'
    ]
```

**My Viewsets:**

```
class UserUpdateAPIView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
queryset = User.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserEditSerializer

@detail_route(methods=['PATCH'])
def edit(self, request):
    user_obj = User.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
    print(user_obj)
    serializer = UserEditSerializer(user_obj, data=request.data, partial=True)
    print(request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Data sent with POSTMAN** (json)

```
{ "email": "231@sda.com", "profile": {"bio": "Cant send request" } }
```

**Error:**

```
Profile.Bio cant response true data
```

**Photo:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserEditSerializer's model is `Profile` class. But you are try to pass as object `User` instance. You need to change serializer class:

```
class UserEditSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    bio = serializers.CharField(source='profile.bio')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'bio',
        ]
```

or view:

```
@detail_route(methods=['PATCH'])
def edit(self, request):
    user_obj = Profile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
    serializer = UserEditSerializer(user_obj, data=request.data, partial=True)
```

**UPD**

To make nested relation writable you need to override serializer's `create` and `update` methods, see details in the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).
Example:

```
class UserEditSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    bio = serializers.CharField(source='profile.bio')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'bio',
        ]
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile = validated_data.pop('profile')
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        instance.profile.bio = profile.get('bio', instance.profile.bio)
        instance.profile.save()            
        return instance
```

Also you need to post data like this `{ "email": "231@sda.com", "bio": "Cant send request" }`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163101/discussion-between-neverwalkaloner-and-feed-git).